# Parallax text not working in my html, css and js but i don't have any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, visual-studio

[text is supposed to appear as i scroll down the page like in fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DQYQ.png)

[fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQSRs.png)

i am using a react app for my website too if this helps but i just don't know why its not working, i used the code from this website too help me too [https://www.codehim.com/animation-effects/simple-parallax-effect-in-javascript/#:~:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20add,outer%20height%20of%20the%20elements](https://www.codehim.com/animation-effects/simple-parallax-effect-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20add,outer%20height%20of%20the%20elements).

(this is the html code)

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  return (
    <><><div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
    

      </header>
    </div>
      <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">
          <h1>prizeit</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <h1>Data is your and your to own</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <h1>Welcome to the endless media that rewards you for your Data</h1>
        </div>
      </div></>

    <div class="parallax background">
      <h1>whats up dog</h1>
      <h1>whats up dog</h1>
      <h1>whats up dog</h1>
    </div></>

  
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
(css)


.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #000000;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
 }
body{
  text-align: center;
}

.section{
  height:100vh;
  padding: 2em;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2),.section:nth-of-type(4){
  background-color: rgba(133,133, 133, 0.3);
}

.parallax-background{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 100vh;
}

.parallax-background h1 {
height: 100vh;
padding-bottom: 50vh;
font-size: 5vmax;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

(js)

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});

var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

document.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

})

function outerHeight(el){
  var height = el.offsetHeight;
  var style = getcomputedSyle(el);

  height +=parseInt(style.marginTop)+parseInt(style.marginBottom);
  return height;

}

function parallax(el, speedFactor, outerHeight){
  var foo = document.querySelectorAll(el)

  var getHeight;
  var firstTop;
  var paddingTop = 0;

  foo.forEach(function(subEl){
    firstTop = subEl.getBoundingClientRect().top
  });
}
if (outerHeight){
  getHeight = function(el){
    return outerHeight(el);

  };
  
}else{
  getHeight = function(el){
    return el.clientHeight;

  };

}

function update(){
  var pos = window.scrollY;

  foo.forEach(function(subEl){
    var element = subEl;
    var top = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var height = getHeight(element);

    element.style.top = -(Math.round((firstTop-pos)*speedFactor)) +"px";

  });

document.addEventListener("scroll",update,true)
document.addEventListener("resize",update)
update()


};

parallax(".parallax-background",-0.6);

fullpage.intialize("#fullpage",{
  css3:false,
  scrollBar:true
});
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thnx, sorry quite new to coding :)